# Win32 C++ Resizing Window Leaves Artifacts in RDP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a simple Win32 program that does the following

1) Creates a Window

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_LEFT |
    WS_EX_LTRREADING |
    WS_EX_RIGHTSCROLLBAR |
    WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE |
    WS_EX_APPWINDOW,
    wc.lpszClassName,
    L"App Name",
    WS_CAPTION |
    WS_VISIBLE |
    WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |
    WS_CLIPCHILDREN |
    WS_SYSMENU |
    WS_OVERLAPPED |
    WS_MINIMIZEBOX, 0, 0, 540, 180, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);
```

Then

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{


switch (message)
{
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        HDC hdc;
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

                    // code here (not shown) calculates pixel size of text with GetTextExtentPoint32
                    // resizes window to fit text with MoveWindow
                   MoveWindow(hWnd, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right - rect.left, height  + borderSize, false);
                    // writes text to window with DrawText

                    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    }

    break;
case WM_CLOSE:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This works fine on desktop without an issue, Window looks fine and displays as expected.

However on RDP the following artifacts are present:

- The pre-resized versions of Window remains i.e. you can see both the old border and the new border
- An image from the background of where Window was created is blended into the Window
- Moving the Window around the screen does not remove the artifacts
- Minimizing the Window and opening it again does remove the artifacts

If I minimize the Remote Desktop client, and switch back to it, the Window is displayed as expected.

Other programs don't show this behavior during the RDP session.

RDP client is on Win10 x64, target machines are Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Tried with repaint set to TRUE in MoveWindow but this had no affect.

Comment: Is `WM_PAINT` the best choice for your window resize calculation? It seems inherently dangerous to me that you do anything in a paint handler that can trigger more painting.

Comment: Moving a window inside your `WM_PAINT` handler doesn't look like an ideal solution. Unrelated to your issue, but ORing [WS_OVERLAPPED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx) doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: Ok I can move it out, I normally write console program not GUI. However I thought with bRepaint = false it should not trigger more painting.

Comment: As for use of WS_OVERLAPPED, the only reason I used it is I was re-creating a WPF program and that is what it passed to CreateWindow

Comment: I think you should keep only the drawing part in WM_PAINT, what to draw would ideally be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by removing WS_VISIBLE from my CreateWindowEx command, resized the Window first, then after resizing Window called

```
ShowWindow(hWnd,SW_SHOW);
```

I also removed the window resize from WM_PAINT, however this did not fix the issue.